# Vba Excel, html automation, send file name to input=file

Tags: html, excel, vba, file, input

i'm automating a Web page using Excel VBA. On this page I have to upload a file, to do so I have to click on the Browse button and then choose the file from the window "choose File to upload ". The problem and that at this point the VBA code crashes while waiting for the file to be selected.

Image:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <Meta Name="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MYPAGE/js-css/calendario/calendario.css" type="text/css">
      </link>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MYPAGE/js-css/Style.css" type="text/css" title="classico"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href='/MYPAGE/css/dhtmlxmenu.css'          type="text/css" title="classico"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href='/MYPAGE/css/context.css'             type="text/css" title="classico"/>
      <style>
         a {
         font-family: arial, verdana;
         font-size: 8pt;
         }
         #loading{
         position:absolute;
         left:300px;
         top:180px;
         z-index:1;
         font:40px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         color:#ffffff;
         padding:20px;
         background-color:#000000;
         border:1px solid black;
         /* for IE */
         filter:alpha(opacity=60);
         /* CSS3 standard */
         opacity:0.6;
         visibility: hidden;
         }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.css' />
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>  
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js"></script>  
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgridcell.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/ext/dhtmlxgrid_drag.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/ext/dhtmlxgrid_nxml.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/ext/dhtmlxgrid_selection.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/ext/dhtmlxgrid_deprecated.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src='/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlxTreeGrid/codebase/dhtmlxtreegrid.js' ></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/dhtmlGridCellSelfin.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/hashTable.js"></script> 
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/calcola_totali.js"></script> 
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/report.js"></script> 
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/calendario/CalendarPopup.js"></script>
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/calendario/calendarFunction.js"></script> 
      <script language="JavaScript" src="/MYPAGE/js-css/standardFunction.js"></script>
      <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
         var newwindow = '';
         var mygrid;
         var testata         = "Nome File,Data,Caricatore,Operazione,MSISDN OK,MSISDN Scartate,MSISDN Doppie,Scarica Originale,Scarica Scarti,Scarica Doppi";
         //var footer          = "";
         var ampiezzaColonne = "280,90,100,100,70,70,70,80,80,80";
         var allineamento    = "left,center,left,center,center,center,center,center,center,center";
         var tipoColonne     = "ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro";
         var actionUrl       = "/MYPAGE/ElencoFile.do";
         var celleAbilitateDettaglio = "" ;
         var celleAbilitateArray = celleAbilitateDettaglio.split(",");
         
         var celleAbilitateTotali = "" ;
         var celleTotaliArray     = celleAbilitateTotali.split(",");
         var coloreCelleDetail    = "";
         
         
         function doOnLoad(){
         
         //loadError();
          mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
          buildTreeGrid();   
         }
         function buildTreeGrid(){
          
          mygrid.imgURL = '/MYPAGE/immagini/dhtmlxGrid/';
          mygrid.setHeader(testata);
          //mygrid.attachFooter(footer);  
          mygrid.setInitWidths(ampiezzaColonne);
          mygrid.setColTypes(tipoColonne);
          mygrid.setColAlign(allineamento);
          mygrid.setOnLoadingStart(StartLoading);
          mygrid.setOnLoadingEnd(StopLoading);  
          mygrid.enableAutoHeigth(true,"350");
          //mygrid.enableAutoHeigth(false,"150","10");  
          mygrid.setOnRowDblClickedHandler(dettaglio);  
          mygrid.enableEditEvents(false, false, false); 
          mygrid.setOnKeyPressed(selezionaCelle);   
          mygrid.setColumnColor(coloreCelleDetail); 
          //PER LA FORMATTAZIONE USARE TYPE EDNRO UTILIZZIAMO le colonne per le quali calcolare i totali
          mygrid.i18n.decimal_separator=",";
          mygrid.i18n.group_separator=".";
          for (var j = 0 ; j < celleTotaliArray.length; j++){
           var tot = celleTotaliArray[j];
           var ind = tot.substring(3);
           mygrid.setNumberFormat("0,000",ind); 
          }      
          
          mygrid.init();
          mygrid.enableBlockSelection();
          mygrid.loadXML(actionUrl);
          //mygrid.loadXML('/MYPAGE/pages/Test.xml');
         } 
         
         function scaricaOriginale(valore){
          document.ReportForm.action = "/MYPAGE/ScaricaCsv.do";
          document.ReportForm.id.value = valore;
          document.ReportForm.submit();
         }
         function scaricaScarti(valore){
          document.ReportForm.action = "/MYPAGE/ScaricaScartati.do";
          document.ReportForm.id.value = valore;
          document.ReportForm.submit();
         }
         function scaricaDoppi(valore){
          document.ReportForm.action = "/MYPAGE/ScaricaDoppi.do";
          document.ReportForm.id.value = valore;
          document.ReportForm.submit();
         }
         
         function scaricaListaVip(){
          document.ReportForm.action = "/MYPAGE/ScaricaCvsDati.do";
          document.ReportForm.submit();
         }
         
         function submitControl(){
          var operation = document.forms[0].tipoOperazione.value;
          var file = document.getElementById('uploadFile').value;
          if (operation == 'null' || file == '')
           alert('- Bisogna selezionare il tipo di operazione da eseguire \n- Bisogna specificare un file da caricare');
          else{
           document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "visible";
           document.forms[0].submit();
          } 
         }
         
          function selezionaCelle(code,ctrl,shift) {
            if(code==67&&ctrl){
             mygrid.setCSVDelimiter("\t");
             mygrid.copyBlockToClipboard();
             return true;
            }
         }
         
          function submitPrint(TipoStampa){
           
           apriNuovaFinestra('/MYPAGE/pages/common/lanciaAction.jsp', 600 , 300); 
         
           }
          
           
         //richiamato al momento dell'export consente l'apertura della finestra contenente la clessidra
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="doOnLoad();">
      <form name="FileUpload" method="post" action="/MYPAGE/LoadListe.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div id="Text_Body">
            &gt;&gt; Report Caricamento Liste
            <div id="loading">
               <img src="/MYPAGE/immagini/indicator.gif">
               Loading...
            </div>
            <div id="body_content">
               <div id ="Table">
                  <div id="tr">
                     <select name="tipoOperazione" class="tipoCalendario" style="width : 300pxpx;">
                        <option value="null">Selezionare un valore per l'operazione</option>
                        <option value="add">Inserimento</option>
                        <option value="del">Cancellazione</option>
                     </select>
                     &#32;&#32; File: &#32;
                     <input type="file" name="theFile" value="" style="width : 500pxpx;" id="uploadFile">
                  </div>
                  <br><br>
                  <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
                     <img src='/MYPAGE/immagini/carica_off.gif'
                        onclick="javascript:submitControl();"
                        onmouseover="this.src='/MYPAGE/immagini/carica_on.gif'"
                        onmouseout="this.src='/MYPAGE/immagini/carica_off.gif'"
                        />
                     <img  src='/MYPAGE/immagini/scaricaCVS_off.gif'
                        onclick="javascript:scaricaListaVip();"
                        onmouseover="this.src='/MYPAGE/immagini/scaricaCVS_on.gif'"
                        onmouseout="this.src='/MYPAGE/immagini/scaricaCVS_off.gif'"
                        />
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="gridbox" style=" width: 100%; height: 400px;" ></div>
            <div id="msg_gridbox" class="messageGrid" ><IMG src="/MYPAGE/immagini/indicator.gif">Caricamento dati ...</div>
         </div>
      </form>
      <form name="ReportForm" method="post" action="/MYPAGE/ScaricaCsv.do">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
      </form>
</html>
```

and this is my VBA code:

```
Sub ie_automatic
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
        objIE.Visible = True

        objIE.Navigate "mylink"
        objIE.FullScreen = False

        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        objIE.Document.getElementById("j_user").Value = myuser
        objIE.Document.getElementById("j_password").Value = mypsw
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
        objIE.Document.getElementById("idsubmit").Click

        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        For Each objLink In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")

            If objLink.href = "mylink1" Then
               objLink.Click
               Exit For
            End If

        Next objLink

        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    For Each element In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
        If element.innerText = "Cancellazione" Then
            element.Selected = True
        End If
    Next

    For Each element In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("input")

        element.Click
        Exit For

    Next

            For Each element In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("img")
        If element.src = "mylink/carica_off.gif" Then
            element.Click
        End If
    Next

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))


    For Each element In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
        If element.innerText = "Inserimento" Then
            element.Selected = True
        End If
    Next

       For Each element In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("input")
        element.Click
    Exit For

    Next


    'click tasto Carica
    For Each element In objIE.Document.frames(0).Document.body.getElementsByTagName("img")
        If element.src = "mylink/carica_off.gif" Then
            element.Click
        End If
    Next

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))


   End If

fine:
    For Each objLink In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

        If objLink.href = "mylink/Logoff.do" Then
           objLink.Click
           Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
           Exit For
        End If

    Next objLink
    objIE.FullScreen = False
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing

    'Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Call emailimage
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

When I get to the point where I make element and click the code crashes while waiting for you to select the file in the dialog box.

Help me understand how to pass the value to the control

```
< input type =  "File " name =  "Thefile " value =  "" style =  "width: 500pxpx; " id =  "uploadfile " >
```

which if I understand correctly is associated with the function Submitcontrol () without having to open the dialog box that blocks everything?
Infinitely Thank you

Comment: So you want the user to manually select the file in the middle of your automation?

Comment: Hello, no I would like the automation to pass the file path through a variable that I have omitted from the code. The problem that I have to solve is how to pass this path to automation, because as I was describing as soon as I make element.click the dialog box opens and the code stops at that point ... I wanted to understand how to do it through the object that I create in my vba ...

Comment: I'm presuming that the popup is not html based window but is an actual file picker (windows based) popup?

Comment: ^^ Can you show us what pops us (so to speak!) ?

Comment: in my answer , the popup windows

Comment: While what you're trying to do is doable with VBA, it really isn't good use of Excel VBA.  A better approach would be to use Visual Studio for the Website and file upload.  If there is some processing you need to do through Excel, then the VS ASP page you've built could call Excel and perform whatever actions are necessary.  If you don't have Visual Studio, you can download [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)

Comment: i mean i have to create an automatism with visual studio to do what i do with vba? what I have to do is open this site, log in with my user and password, navigate to the page where I posted the code and then upload the file and make sure that the list is uploaded via a second click on the charge button .....
can I do this with visual studio? if you could give me some advice?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the choose upload file windows that show when i click the "browse" button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QCjk.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the above into your question and delete this answer (which is really an edit).